How to get Sales order , Quotation , Invoice details in custom function for customers module?
I am pretty new to zoho books. Here, I am trying to create a custom function in zoho books. Right now, I just want to know whether a particular customer has invoice or quotation or sales order.
estimatesResponse = zoho.books.getRecords("estimates",organizationID,{"contact_id":customerID});
info estimatesResponse;

This is what I tried. This code retrieves all the quotations of all the customers. That is not what I need. I want to know whether one particular customer has quotations created for them or not.
Does anyone have any solution for this?
